# Problems with using include command in PHP

Tags: php, function, include

I have a PHP  script that executes another PHP script(that contains quite a lot of functions some being recursive) using the include method , multiple times, but the second time i get a error saying that one of the function in the "included" PHP script can not be redeclared.

Now i get that what include does is just inserting the commands from the referenced script in the script that called it and thus I have like the same functions declare too many times resulting in a abomination.

So, could somebody tell me how i should approach this problem?

This is the included script

```
<?php
$_SESSION['det']=0;
$x=array();
function valid($k)
{
for($i=1;$i<$k;$i++)
    if($GLOBALS['x'][$i]==$GLOBALS['x'][$k])
        return 0;
return 1;
}
function semn($k)
{
$nr=0;
for($i=1;$i<$k;$i++)
    for($j=$i+1;$j<=$k;$j++)
        if($GLOBALS['x'][$i]>$GLOBALS['x'][$j])
            $nr++;
if($nr%2==0)
    return 1;
else
    return -1;
}
 function determinant($k)
 {
$prod=1;
for($i=0;$i<$k;$i++)
    $prod*=$_SESSION['matrix'][$i][$GLOBALS['x'][$i+1]-1];
$_SESSION['det']+=semn($k)*$prod;
   }
   function solve($k,$n)
   {
for($i=1;$i<=$n;$i++)
{
    $GLOBALS['x'][$k]=$i;
    if(valid($k))
        if($k==$n)
        {
            determinant($k);
        }
        else
            solve($k+1,$n);
}
 }
   $n=$_SESSION['size'];
 solve(1,$n);
 unset($x);
 ?>
```

And this is the script thats includes.

```
 <?php


  include 'determinant.php';


  if(!$_SESSION['det'])
   {
       echo "The inverse cant be calculated cause the determinant is equla to 0.";
   }
    else
     {
$detA=$_SESSION['det'];

//Transpusa
for($i=0;$i<$_SESSION['size']-1;$i++)
    for($j=$i+1;$j<$_SESSION['size'];$j++)
    {
        $aux=$_SESSION['matrix'][$i][$j];
        $_SESSION['matrix'][$i][$j]=$_SESSION['matrix'][$j][$i];
        $_SESSION['matrix'][$j][$i]=$aux;
    }


$Dcar=array();

//Matricile caracteristice
for($i=0;$i<$_SESSION['size'];$i++)
{
    for($j=0;$j<$_SESSION['size'];$j++)
    {

        $r=0;
        $c=0;
        $semn=1;
        $a=array();

        $_SESSION['matrix'][$i][$j]
        for($m=0;$m<$_SESSION['size'];$m++)
        {
            if($m==$i)
                continue;
            else
            {

                for($n=0;$n<$_SESSION['size'];$n++)
                {
                    if($n==$j)
                    continue;
                    else
                    {
                        $a[$r][$c]=$_SESSION['matrix'][$m][$n];
                        $c++;
                    }
                }
                $r++;
                $c=0;
            }
        }

        //Apelarea functiei determinant pentru fiecare matrice
        $aux=$_SESSION['matrix'];
        $_SESSION['matrix']=$a;
        $_SESSION['size']-=1;

        include 'determinant.php';
        $_SESSION['matrix']=$aux;
        $_SESSION['size']+=1;

        $Dcar[$i][$j]=($semn*$_SESSION['det'])/$detA;
        $semn*=-1;


    }
}


for($i=0;$i<$_SESSION['size'];$i++)
{
    for($j=0;$j<$_SESSION['size'];$j++)
        echo $Dcar[$i][$j]." ";
    echo "<br>";
}


 }

  ?>
```

Comment: Have you considered using `include_once` rather than `include`?

Comment: It would be helpful if you post some code samples.

Comment: Try with `require`. And paste some examples.

Comment: I inserted the code right this moment. Please ignore the comments is romanian.

Answer (score 0):

Use `include_once()` function.

Follow documentation:

> This is a behavior similar to the include statement, with the only 
>   difference being that if the code from a file has already been 
>   included, it will not be included again. As the name suggests, it will
>   be included just once.

Comment: Using include_once it gives me the same result of the first time, which is bad because I use other variables the next times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use require_once() instead. It's all in the name in this case ;-)

Comment: It still looks like it uses the old variables.